# PDFtk not writing to some multiline fields

Tags: php, pdf, pdftk

I'm using PDFtk to fill out interactive PDFs from form entries, but some of the fields in the PDF remain blank after using the `fill_form` command to merge the FDF file. It seems to be affecting some of the multiline fields (`FieldFlags: 4096`), but not all multiline fields.

This is a sample of the field data of the interactive PDF from `pdftk /pdf-forms/raw/idaho.pdf dump_data_fields`:

```
---
FieldType: Text
FieldName: Employer Name Address incl zip
FieldNameAlt: Employer (Name & Address incl. zip)
FieldFlags: 4096
FieldValue: 
FieldJustification: Left
---
FieldType: Text
FieldName: CarrierAdministrator Claim Number
FieldNameAlt: Carrier/Administrator Claim Number
FieldFlags: 0
FieldValue: 
FieldJustification: Left
---
FieldType: Text
FieldName: Jurisdiction
FieldNameAlt: Jurisdiction
FieldFlags: 0
FieldValue: 
FieldJustification: Left
---
FieldType: Text
FieldName: Jurisdiction Claim No
FieldNameAlt: Jurisdiction Claim No.
FieldFlags: 0
FieldValue: 
FieldJustification: Left
---
FieldType: Text
FieldName: Employers Location Address if different
FieldNameAlt: Employer’s Location Address (if different)
FieldFlags: 4096
FieldValue: 
FieldJustification: Left
---
FieldType: Text
FieldName: Claims Admin Name Address Phone Number
FieldNameAlt: Claims Admin (Name, Address & Phone Number)
FieldFlags: 4096
FieldValue: 
FieldJustification: Left
---
```

Here's what the temp FDF file looks like:

```
%FDF-1.2 1 0 obj<</FDF<< 
/Fields[
    <</T(Employer Name Address incl zip)/V(Name Test Submit)>>
    <</T(CarrierAdministrator Claim Number)/V(Carrier/Administrator Claim Number)>>
    <</T(Jurisdiction)/V(Jurisdiction)>>
    <</T(Jurisdiction Claim No)/V(Jurisdiction Claim No.)>>
    <</T(Employers Location Address if different)/V(Employer’s Location Address (if different))>>
    <</T(Claims Admin Name Address Phone Number)/V(Claims Admin Name)>>
] >> >>
endobj
trailer
<</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EOF
```

And here's a sample of the code I'm using if it helps:

```
$data = [
    'Employer Name Address incl zip' => $entry[15],               // multiline blank
    'CarrierAdministrator Claim Number' => $entry[93],            // multiline filled
    'Jurisdiction' => $entry[95],                                 // single line filled
    'Jurisdiction Claim No' => $entry[96],                        // single line filled
    'Employers Location Address if different' => $entry["98.1"],  // multiline filled
    'Claims Admin Name Address Phone Number' => $entry[155],      // multiline blank
];

$pdf = new PdfForm('/pdf-forms/raw/idaho.pdf', $data);
$pdf->save('/pdf-forms/flat/idaho.pdf');
$pdf->download();
```

Looking for some kind of solution to get all the fields filling, or at least for some way to test why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a double space in some of the field names.

- `Employer Name  Address incl zip` rather than `Employer Name Address incl zip`
- `Claims Admin Name Address  Phone Number` rather than `Claims Admin Name Address Phone Number`

Corrected FDF:

```
%FDF-1.2
1 0 obj <<
  /FDF <<
    /Fields [ <<
        /T (Employer Name  Address incl zip)
        /V (Name Test Submit)
      >> <<
        /T (CarrierAdministrator Claim Number)
        /V (Carrier/Administrator Claim Number)
      >> <<
        /T (Jurisdiction)
        /V (Jurisdiction)
      >> <<
        /T (Jurisdiction Claim No)
        /V (Jurisdiction Claim No.)
      >> <<
        /T (Employers Location Address if different)
        /V (Employer’s Location Address \(if different\))
      >> <<
        /T (Claims Admin Name Address  Phone Number)
        /V (Claims Admin Name)
      >> ]
  >>
>>
endobj

trailer
<<
  /Root 1 0 R
>>
%%EOF
```

Comment: Wow, I've been looking at this issue for days now, and this fixed it. Thank you, how did you find that? There are actually a lot more fields in this form, and there are several others having this problem. How did you find where the extra space was?

Comment: A little explorative programming. https://gist.github.com/dwarring/47df7f56f44bc0d622047302b0c92193 in Perl 6 using some PDF modules that I'm developing https://github.com/p6-pdf. Low key and still under construction.